# computer (host) names agains AD login

Tags: active-directory

Is there any software or real-time tool i can see the computer (host) names / ip address which an AD user logged into?

Comment: You'll have to scrape event logs on all your domain controller computers to get this. For all that I've seen this asked-for I'm amazed that there isn't a product that does it. It probably wouldn't even be that difficult to write (at least, in a manner that works in a passable fashion... it's just another loose convergence multi-master database replication problem, so it has a lot of hairy edge cases).

Answer (score 1):

Good answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/262154/windows-server-2003-terminal-server-easiest-way-to-view-all-mapped-drives-for-all) from [Garrett](https://serverfault.com/users/7320/garrett).

> Add something like the following to your logon script

```
echo %date%,%time%,%computername%,%username% >> \\fileserver\hiddenshare$\drives.csv
net use >> \\fileserver\hiddenshare$\drives.csv
```

Comment: This is what I like to use.

Answer (score 0):

Manageengine makes a product that will do the log parsing for you, It's not realtime (but you can re-run it)

http://www.manageengine.com/products/ad-manager/index.html

Answer (score -2):

If you're running DHCP on the AD server you can check DHCP leases - might be better than nothing.

Comment: but DHCP lease never shows you the username logged into it.